# How do "apps" work from django's point of view?

Tags: python, django

First of all, the question is technical, not conceptual.

The docs mention, in various places, that you are supposed to put in `INSTALLED_APPS` the root module of your app. However, what is that module supposed to contain?

Most of the files created by `startapp myapp` are just there by convention. For example `urls, views, admin` files are imported from other modules by fully qualified name, and could really be anywhere, so they are just conventions. The only thing that seems to be "hard-coded" in the django logic is the `models.py`.

So, from the `INSTALLED_APPS` point of view, does an *app* consist solely of its `models.py`? Or is there something else I'm missing? And does the documentation explicitly state this anywhere?

Comment: I'm no expert in the Django internals, but does this page have the information you want? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/. In particular: `It is important to understand that a Django application is just a set of code that interacts with various parts of the framework. There’s no such thing as an Application object. However, there’s a few places where Django needs to interact with installed applications, mainly for configuration and also for introspection. That’s why the application registry maintains metadata in an AppConfig instance for each installed application.`

Comment: @RobinZigmond: thanks. the problem is what exactly *configuration and retrospection* includes. I can't find it anywhere in the docs. The sentence following, seems to enforce my suspicions that only models matter: `There’s no restriction that a project package can’t also be considered an application and have models, etc. (which would require adding it to INSTALLED_APPS).`

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to `@RobinZigmond` for pointing me to the correct part of the docs.

It seems that indeed, everything is a convention, with the exception of `models` submodule. The description of the [initialization process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#initialization-process) states that for each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`

1. the module `myapp` is imported. models are not ready yet.
2. the `models` submodule if `myapp` is imported. **you must import of define** your models in `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`
3. sets the corresponding `ready` flag to `True` in the application registry